# Вставка векторной фигуры Ellipse, Rectangle, Line, TextBox и др. в ячейку таблицы MSWord 2010

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-word, shape

Приветствую господа программисты! )) Вчера целый день потратил на попытки вставить фигуру "Ellipse" в объединённую ячейку таблицы MSWord 2010. Казалось бы простая задача, но код на C# (WPF) отказывается корректно работать:

```
        Interop.Word.Shape shape = documentWord.Shapes.AddShape(Core.Mso~Oval, 6, 6, 10, 10, documentWord.Tables[0].Cell(1,5).Range);
        Interop.Word.InlineShape inlineShape = shape.ConvertToInlineShape();
        inlineShape.LockAncore = (int)True;
```

Эллипс вставляется не в ячейку таблицы, а в основной текст над таблицей. В конце строки (в скобках) "Range" - это Ancore(Якорь) привязки фигуры документа к диапазону текста. Если попробовать сразу создать inlineShape в таблице, то в предлагаемых вариантах нет эллипсов, прямоугольников, скругленных прямоугольников, но есть Picture, Text и др. Вручную, программно добавленный эллипс, легко перемещается в ячейку, но записать макрос действий не получается т.к. в этом режиме указатель мыши не захватывает фигуру для перетаскивания.
Пишу программу, которая добавляет в документ MSWord сотни графических примитивов.
Help, please ))

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался.
Если указать в качестве якоря ячейку таблицы, то координаты задаются всё равно относительно левого/верхнего угла листа (не `inline`).

Особенность якоря в том, что при компоновке нескольких фигур с одним якорем относительно друг друга они не разъезжаются!
Микрософт, ты "гений"!